# Replace content by key in JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I've the JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
    "Url": "placeholder",
}
```

I'd like to write a Powershell script which replaces the value ("placeholder") by key ("Url").

I know how to replace content by I don't know how to save it back to the file.

```
$snapshot = (Get-Content settings.json | ConvertFrom-Json)
$snapshot.Url = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it back using the `Set-Content` cmdlet. E. g.:

```
$snapshot | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content
```